# Switch statement, two similar cases in different case

Tags: c++, switch-statement, cin

If I want to create a menu with options, so e.g

If I have two cases, A and B, within those they have the option to write C.
A C and BC as input should be different things, and not conflict. How would that work?

```
char ch;

cout << "Write in command: ";
cin >> ch; 

switch(ch) {
    case 'A': {
        cin >> ch;
        case 'C': cout << "C"; break;
        break;
    }
    case 'B': {
        cin >> ch;
        case 'C': cout << "C"; break;
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just use an `if` inside the `case`.

Comment: With this structure you'd have to have a sub `switch` in each `case` which is obviously needlessly obfuscated and ugly, so... just use an `if` statement.

Comment: Please explain why you need to write such cryptic code. [What's the real problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you are trying to solve?

Comment: even after you change the value of `ch`, `switch(ch)` still uses the older value, so if you are trying to run all sub-levels of your menu-program using the same variable `ch` then it will run all cases without checking , so use `if` statements or another `switch`. In your code since the later cases are inside cases so no value other than the starting value `A` being false can stop them from running

Answer (score 1):

You have to use another switch case or if statement for each of the cases.

I'd personally recommend using an if statement if you're going to be using a small amount of items since another switch case would make it ugly in my eyes.

Nested switch case.

```
switch(ch) {
    case 'A': {
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch) {
            case 'C': cout << "C"; break;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 'B': {
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch) {
            case 'C': cout << "C"; break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Nested if statement.

```
switch(ch) {
    case 'A': {
        cin >> ch;
        if (ch == 'C') {
            std::cout << 'C';   
        }
        break;
    }
    case 'B': {
        cin >> ch;
        if (ch == 'C') {
            std::cout << 'C';   
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using `std::cout`, you should write `std::cin`.